# Question Revision Diff not showing the full difference

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown-rendering, revision-history

In this question revision

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39236576/revisions

on revision #2

there is a difference between "side by side" and "side by side markdown", it looks like the "side by side markdown" is showing the right difference but the other views seem to omit some text from the original answer

Throws.InstanceOf());

vs

```
Throws.InstanceOf<exceptionType>());
```

if you look at the text content they are the same but when they are rendered it becomes different. Is this an expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text `<exceptionType>` when outside of a code block is interpreted as HTML instead - invalid HTML which is automatically stripped by the system so that it does not render or mess up the structure of the page. It appears when inside the code block because it is now properly identified as code.